# Cannot create unbalanced journal entry in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-11

I am using odoo version 12.0+e  .  Whenever I go to POS and Close a Session by Hitting the "validate closing & post entries" button it shows loading screen and after a few minutes it shows "Cannot create unbalanced journal entry." error. I am running odoo trial in cloud server. the problem screenshot has been tagged.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfrbW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating separate jounral entry line you have to setup vals for debit and credit line then create jounral entry record. This will solve your problem

[Show this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-resolve-cannot-create-unbalanced-journal-entry-while-closing-session-in-pos-118162)